# AWS DMS Service and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms, sap-bw

I have source system in SAP BW and want to migrate data into AWS S3 bucket using AWS DMS (Database migration service). All the source data are in flat file format (Either .CVS or .xls).

How to connect to SAP BW from AWS DMS service and extract data from source?

Comment: If all your data is in cvs or excel... what's the connection needed for?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you run into any issues? Remember that we expect a minimum a research effort from you if you want us to invest time for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same thing, but you can check this manual on how to migrate SAP ASE database as source.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SAP.html